# Google Cloud API - Get Projects from User

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

I know that using the Google Cloud User Accounts API (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/clouduseraccounts/beta/) it should be possible to enter a Project ID and obtain a list of user accounts associated with this.

Is there a GCP/Google API which does the opposite however and you can supply it with user (ID, email etc.) and it will list projects associated with this user?

I am not too familiar with GCP APIs so trial and error so far...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cloudresourcemanager.projects.list should be the API you're looking for: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/list

API Explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/Resource/cloudresourcemanager/v1/cloudresourcemanager.projects.list